# How to add Button to FeedListItem

Tags: sapui5

I want to add two buttons to a FeedListItem similar to the NotificationnListItem.

```
<List headerText="Feed Entries" items="{ path : '/userFeedBack', mode : 'OneWay' }">
    <FeedListItem sender="@{UserScreenname} ({UserName})"
        icon="{ProfileImgUrl}" senderPress=".navToUser"
        iconPress=".navToUser" 
        iconDensityAware="false" info="{Type}"
        timestamp="{ path : 'Time', formatter : '.notificationListItemFormatted' }"
        text="{TweetText} ({Total} times)">
    </FeedListItem>
</List>
```

[image: List view]

It should look like this. How can I these buttons or is there any other list control which I can use here?

Answer (score 0):

For buttons, you will have to use different type of List Items. The FeedListItem does not support any aggregation. I would suggest the following options:

1. sap.m.NotificationListItem
2. sap.m.CustomListItem: Here, you will need to create a layout, where the image will come, where the text and the buttons will render.
3. Create a custom control by Extending FeedListItem and add 'buttons' aggregation to it.

Let me know if you need more inputs.

Comment: the 3rd option seems good. but how i can extend my control and add button's aggregations to it. any help regarding that

Answer (score 0):

XML Code :

```
<List id="notificationList" class="sapContrast sapContrastPlus">
                <NotificationListItem
                        description="Information of List Item 1"
                        showCloseButton="false"
                        datetime="1 hour"
                        unread="true"
                        press="onListItemPress"
                        authorName="Jean Doe"
                        authorPicture="sap-icon://globe">
                    <buttons>
                        <Button text="Accept" type="Accept" ></Button>
                        <Button text="Reject" type="Reject" class="sapUiLargeMarginEnd" ></Button>
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://thumb-up" class="sapUiLargeMarginBegin" ></Button>
                    </buttons>
                </NotificationListItem>
                <NotificationListItem
                        description="Information of List Item 2"
                        showCloseButton="false"
                        datetime="1 hour"
                        unread="true"
                        priority="None"
                        authorName="Jean Doe"
                        authorPicture="sap-icon://world">
                    <buttons>
                        <Button text="Accept" type="Accept" ></Button>
                        <Button text="Reject" type="Reject" class="sapUiLargeMarginEnd" ></Button>
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://thumb-down" class="sapUiLargeMarginBegin" ></Button>
                    </buttons>
                </NotificationListItem> 
            </List>
```